# systemd: stop all uninstalled units

Tags: systemd

I have some systemd units installed and running. Let's say I manually uninstall `foo.service` by

- removing its .service (and .socket) files
- removing all symlinks (e.g from default.target.wants/)

I can run `systemctl daemon-reload`, and then I see:

```
# systemctl status foo.service
foo.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2013-07-08 13:50:29 EST; 48s ago
 Main PID: 1642 (node)
```

So systemd knows that it's not installed, and that it is running. **Is there some command I can use to stop all running services which no longer have a unit file?**

---

**Things I've already considered:**

- `systemctl isolate <current-target>`

  This would have the side effect of stopping other manually-started services that aren't required by the current target.
- Use `systemctl disable` instead of manually removing files

  I'd like to, but this script may be run from a host machine with access to the file system of a running container - it can't call `systemd` directly.
- Use `systemctl stop foo.service`

  This implies I know which services have been uninstalled. I don't want to have to figure this out (or remember it), I want a general command that can be run at any time to stop any lingering services.

Comment: Why don't you stop the service first, and then remove it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ideally that will happen, but I want to be confident that should something go wrong, I can stop services that shouldn't be running. Particularly during development of my scripts, where bugs will surely be present.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm just starting with systemd (better late than never) but from what you're saying, it almost sounds like systemd has a weak assurance about its stored state vs. the runtime environment.  Is this really the case?  I've been in a runit environment for some time so this is a little foreign to me at the moment - removal of the service link (which is a rough equivilent of what you are doing with .service/.socket removal) *forces* the service to terminate, so it looks like I'll have to re-learn some behaviors with systemd...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the mailing list, and Lennart Poettering responded with the following advice:

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-July/012083.html

Quoting here for posterity:

---

So, the correct way to handle this is to make sure the packages in
question contain the right scriplets that terminate all units they
include before deinstallation. Of course, there'll always be broken
packages like this I fear, hence I can totally see your usecase.

There's currently no nice way to handle this, but what you can do is this:

```
$ systemctl --all --type=not-found --type=error
```

This will list you all units where the load state is either "error" or
"not-found" (note that 'not-found' is available only in very recent
versions, and in older systemd versions was just a special case of
'error'. The command line above works for all versions). The --type=
switch is used to filter unit types, but actually also can be used to
filter for the load state.

Then filter out the first column:

```
$ systemctl --no-legend --all --type=not-found --type=error | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

This will give you a list of unit files which got referenced or started
but have no unit file installed. Then use this to stop the units:

```
$ systemctl stop `systemctl --no-legend -all --type=not-found --type=error | awk '{ print $1}'`
```